# how to suppress the login screen in Azure AAD authentication

Tags: azure, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, adal

I have created an Azure app. After granted by user(once in lifetime
), it fetches the users outlook mailbox data with help of accessToken. The Microsoft account is part of my org which uses SSO. So, if i am pre logged in via SSO in browser, how can I get rid of the  un-neccesary login screen, which comes pre-populated with my email id, and I only have to click to choose the user account.
How could i remove that login screen from this flow?

Comment: You can specify `login_hint=user@domain.com` with the username in the authorization URL to tell AAD which account the user could use. Try it out at least :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify `login_hint=user@domain.com` with the username in the authorization URL to tell AAD which account the user could use. If they are already signed-in, it won't prompt the user to select the account.