# How to skip the login screen if user is not pre logged in but authorized the azure app in past

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I have created an Azure app. After granted permission by user(once in lifetime ), my Azure+JS code fetches the users' outlook mailbox data with help of graphAPI+accessToken.

The Microsoft account is part of my org(office365). So when I go to my website(*which is using the APP plus JS code to send graphAPI*).

If the user is pre logged-in, I have suppressed the extra login-page.

Refer [how to suppress the login screen in Azure AAD authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070296/how-to-suppress-the-login-screen-in-azure-aad-authentication) Thanks @juunas

But if the user is **NOT** pre logged in to the office365 account, user is redirected to the office365 login. I do not want my user to see this login page each time when user is not pre-logged-in. The user has authorised this app and this wont be a good user experience though.

I have gone through the docs, which says this is possible through ADAL.js.But I coudnt find my exact use case there. Could some one explain/direct me to the correct answer for my problem?

Comment: @juunas, could you please help me here?

Comment: Too bad I don't get notifications for @, but I do watch this tag so no worries, I'll see the question :D

Comment: The user needs to already be logged in to AAD to skip the login screen. Otherwise you cannot skip it.

Comment: ADAL.js is of no help here?

Comment: ADAL.js can do a silent login with a hidden iframe but it requires the user has an active session and also you know the username. If you call ADAL.js acquireToken(), it'll automatically get a new token with this method if needed.

Comment: So that means, i have to give 2 logins to user, one for using my website, and second to login to aad, which will fetch the required data to me. No options?

Comment: Umm, let's take a step back :) Sounds like you want the app to access their data by itself. There are two possible approaches for that. Both require use of a back-end (you can't act as the app from a native app). First option is use a refresh token. Second is to use client credentials. First is harder and a bit more brittle but follows principle of least privilege. There your flow would be: login + consent + get token for your back-end + call back-end + exchange token for tokens to the API you need. Store the returned refresh token securely, and use it the next time you need a new API token.

Comment: The second option is client credentials, where your back-end must require *application permissions* instead of delegated permissions. When an admin consents to these, your back-end can use its client id and secret to get a token whenever it wants. While refresh tokens can expire and are user specific, this access would need to be explicitly revoked so it is more reliable. But, it is also organization-wide access, so that's the downside.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182922/discussion-between-theanubhava-and-juunas).